# abort execution of with statement from context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am relatively new to decorators, context-managers etc in python.
Basically I want to do something like the following:

```
@contextmanager
def cd(to_dir):
    from_dir = os.getcwd()
    try:
        os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(to_dir))
        yield
    except Exception:
        log.error(traceback.format_exc())
        log.error(f"Failed to cd into {to_dir} from {from_dir}")
    finally:
        os.chdir(from_dir)
```

I would like to use it in something like this:

```
with cd('here'):
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

I specifically want to ensure that the body of the with statement is not executed if the `cd` into `here` fails which is why I am attempting to catch the Exception inside the context manager and prevent it from `yield`ing.
However it seems a python generator must yield or I get an error such as:

```
    raise RuntimeError("generator didn't yield") from None                                                                                         |
RuntimeError: generator didn't yield
```

How do I suppress execution of the body of `with` if the chdir fails?

One solution I can think of is this:

```
@contextmanager
def cd(to_dir):
   from_dir = os.getcwd()
   try:
       os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(to_dir))
       yield True
   except Exception:
       log.error(traceback.format_exc())
       log.error(f"Failed to cd into {to_dir} from {from_dir}")
       yield False
   finally:
       os.chdir(from_dir)
```

Then use as follows:

```
with cd('here') as success:
  if success:
    ....
    ....
```

This however does require the additional conditionals whereever the with statement is used, so not so convenient to change everywhere in an existing program. Another issue with this is that if an exception occurs within the body of the `with` statement it also is captured by `except` clause inside the cd contextmanager function leading to a bogus error regarding failing to cd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context manager has no way of skipping the context body, other than raising an error. The [context manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) only allows to return a value to be bound in the body (the target of `as`) but not to indicate skipping the body. Consequently, if entering a context might fail either a) do not suppress the failure exception or b) replace the failure exception with a new exception.

```py
@contextmanager
def cd(to_dir):
    from_dir = os.getcwd()
    # if this fails, the exception bubbles out of the context manager
    os.chdir(os.path.expanduser(to_dir))
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        os.chdir(from_dir)
```

If the initial `os.chdir` fails, the exception will "exit" the context at the `with` statement, without entering the body.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. I now understand the context manager a little better. But still curious on why python doesn't show a `generator doesn't yield` error if the chdir fails in this implementation.

Comment: @backstreetrover The ``"generator didn't yield"`` is a sanity check from the ``contextmanager`` helper – there's also one if the generator yielded too often. The helper expects that there is a single yield or an error, i.e. the context either works exactly as needed or fails explicitly. Since the explicit error already indicates failure, ``contextmanager`` has no reason to signal another failure.